# How to delete matching rows in two tables in ms access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Here is my sql code in ms access:

```
DELETE Table1.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1  = Table2.Field1
```

I want to notice here that Table1 has many columns but Table2 just one column.
I want to delete all rows in Table1 where `Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1`.
But when I execute the code I get this error: Could not delete from specified tables.

However if I use `SELECT` instead of `DELETE` it works fine for displaying rows:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1  = Table2.Field1
```

But I would like to DELETE these rows.

Comment: I was wondering if you've got some kind of lock on the tables (either actual lock on all records, or many-to-many relationship without cascading delete) - that SQL should work (and did when I tested it).   https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/I-get-the-error-message-Could-not-delete-from-the-specified-tables-20dec5e8-5402-4667-802d-523cf4923a46

Answer (score 4):

Consider a subquery. `DELETE` queries in MS Access should have the delete set of rows as the full, standalone result set. In your attempt the result set is two tables even though you only view the first with `SELECT` clause:

```
DELETE Table1.* 
FROM Table1
WHERE Field1 IN (SELECT Field1 FROM Table2)
```

And aligning to ANSI, the asterisk is not needed:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Field1 IN (SELECT Field1 FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would select select the rows ids of the rows into a helper table.
Then

```
delete from Table1 where table1.rowid = helpertable.rowid;
```

then

```
delete from Table2 where table2.rowid = helpertable.rowid;
```

Then

```
drop helpertable;
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working because I want to delete all matching rows between the two tables.

Comment: Err... you're not joining `table2`, so that's sure to fail

Comment: I am beginner in ms access so what is the solution for this code to work? DELETE Table1.*
 FROM Table1
 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1  = Table2.Field1

Comment: Ok I found the solution you have to use the predicatum DISTINCTROW after DELETE

Comment: Have you checked your answer? how can you compare `where table1.rowid = helpertable.rowid` if `helpertable` is not in you `From` section?

Answer (score 1):

Access has weird issues when joining fields in action queries.

Try the following to avoid the join:

```
DELETE *
FROM Table1
WHERE DCount('Field1', 'Table2', 'Field1 = "' & Field1 & '"') <> 0
```